# Filter an object properties by the value of a property

Tags: javascript

for example i have an object with validation rules

```
validationRules = {
    planType: {
        group: 'personalData',
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: 'Required Field'
        }
    },
    name: {
        group: 'personalData',
        required: true,
        pattern: /\w+\s+\w+/,
        messages: {
            required: 'Required Field',
            pattern: 'Insert first and last names'
        }
    },
}
```

I need to validate a form wizard by steps so  I need to make a function just to validate each step

```
function isStepValid() {

    console.log(lastActiveNav);
    const currentStep = lastActiveNav.getAttribute('data-pane');
    var stepRules = validationRules.filter(currentStep); // wont work cause not an array
    console.log(stepRules); // this is the value in the group property in the validationRules



    for (let key in validationRules) {    

        
    }
}
```

I want to loop only through the properties with the value in the group property that match. Sadly i can only find an answer using an array with filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const currentStep = lastActiveNav.getAttribute('data-pane');

Object.keys(validationRules)
  .map(key => validationRules[key])
  .filter(validationRule => validationRule.group === currentStep)
  .forEach(validationRule => {  // forEach/map/reduce depending what you want to do
    // Code here
  })
```

Comment: I figured i could just use an if inside the cycle to check the property but this looks more elegant even replacing the for